# How to handle data correction in Django (but this isn't Django-specific!)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django application that gathers information about composers (in the musical sense) from various sources - APIs, HTTP POSTs, scraping, and so on.

Once this information is aggregated, it's not very high quality. So you might have "J S Bach" in one place, "J. S. Bach" in another, and various other mistakes. This leads to several rows in my table that represent the same person.

I want to eliminate these duplicates, by making "J. S. Bach" the canonical version, and have it so that if we ever see "J S Bach", we know to correct it. In reality, there are quite a lot of variations, but I'm happy for the process of correction to be a manual one with human input.

So my question is, what's the best way to represent this in code? At the moment, my model is:

```
class Composer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Should I:

- Have a new `ComposerCorrection` model, that maps `composer_id` to `canonical_id`?
- Add an optional `canonical_id` to the `Composer` model?
- Some other thing I've not considered?

It's also worth mentioning that there are other relationships that involve composer, such as a `Work` belonging to a `Composer`. When a correction happens, these IDs would also need to be re-pointed somehow, but I think that's not part of the main problem here.

Let me know if you'd like any more information!

Comment: You need to better specify what correcting means to you. If there is a duplicate in the database, is it sufficient to eliminate it? You seem to imply that you wish to create a link to the correct entry, why is this so? Is there new information about the composer that only exists in the wrongly named db row?

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't keep that old composer information around. I want to create a link to the correct entry so that I can perform corrections in the future - almost like spellchecking. So that if I encounter "J S Bach" again, the app can now that it should really be "J. S. Bach". It results in tidier data.

Comment: You might want to think about splitting as well as merging: imagine that you have a bunch of works by "J. C. Bach", but then someone realises that half of them are by Johann Christian and the other half by Johann Christoph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on to [VascoP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9956936/344821) (I'd make this a cmoment but there's a little too much code in it), you could store his `replace_dic` in the database so that you can add corrections through e.g. the Django admin, without having to change any code. This might look like:

```
class ComposerCorrection(models.Model):
    wrong_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    canonical_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

def correct_name(name):
    try:
        return ComposerCorrection.objects.get(wrong_name=name).canonical_name
    except ComposerCorrection.DoesNotExist:
        return name
```

Then you can put `correct_name` in the `save()` method of `Composer` (or as a pre-save signal), and also add VascoP's `correctComposer` function as a post-save signal for `ComposerCorrection` objects, so that adding a new one will fix the database without having to do anything else.

Comment: This is a good db version. My reasoning with having the dic on the code was that with the db version you're hitting the db on every insertion to search for the corrections. Your version does make administrating the corrections much more pleasant though.

Comment: @VascoP Right, it's a trade-off. Which one is better depends entirely on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

When you find a wrongly named Composer you should update these relationships and remove the wrongly named `Composer`:

```
def correctComposer(canonical_composer_name, wrong_composer_name):
  canonical_composer = Composer.objects.get(name__exact=canonical_composer_name)
  wrong_composer = Composer.objects.get(name__exact=wrong_composer_name)

  # repeat this for each relationship
  work = wrong_composer.work_set.all()
  for entry in work:
     entry.composer = canonical_composer

  correction.save()

  wrong_composer.delete()
```

EDIT: That works for previously inserted Composers. For auto-correcting upon insertion a different method could be used since we don't need to create new composers if there's already a canonical composer that suits him.

For this you can keep a dictionary (which should be kept near the model for readability) of frequent mistakes and a correcNames function:

```
replace_dic = {
   'motzart' : 'Mozart',
   'j s bach' : 'J. S. Bach'
   }

def correctNames(name, dic):
   return dic.get(name.lower(), name)
```

By making keys lowercase you get case-insensitive replacement which is kind of a bonus.

And then you might override the `Composer` save method like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.name = correctNames(self.name, replace_dic)
   super(Composer, self).save()
```

Comment: Thanks - the first half of your answer is awesome (so +1!) but the second half isn't quite what I want. I think I'm coming round to the idea of having a separate model that stores mappings of corrections, i.e. that "Motzart" (string) should map to the canonical "Mozart" (Composer foreign key).

Comment: Well, you did leave us to guess your use case, but this mapping to for auto-correct upon insertion is different from what you asked, or would you prefer the auto-correct to run after the wrong insertions?

Comment: I wasn't meaning to sound critical, apologies if my question was unclear. The idea is that the correction happens prior to any insertion.

Comment: @Sam I updated my answer with a possible kind of auto-correct. This would work really well if the mistake list isn't huge.

Comment: `correctNames` could also just be `return dic.get(name, name)` if you wanted to only have whole-composer corrections rather than partial-string corrections. Also, I've just [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9958627/344821) showing how to store `replace_dic` in the database, if you want to be able to add to it without modifying the source.

Comment: @Dougal Thanks for the tip. I changed the correctNames function and added case insensitive replacement.

Answer (score -1):

If Composer only contains name before finishing data collection, for simplicity, I may choose not to normalize composer name to Composer at first, but store them in Work instance directly. Just as

```
class Work(models.Model):
    composer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

And manually filter by composer name and perform batch update in the admin changelist of Work, w/ help of filter and action.

You could then create Composer instances and link Work instance to them, or even use composer_name as primary key of Composer..

Comment: Please comment the reason of down voting thus some improvements can be made. I think simple flat structure is straight for the task, no matter what correction or clustering process will be used afterwards.